# Custom share dialog,not working for some apps

Tags: android, android-intent, dialog, share, evernote

I have implemented a custom share dialog,in my android app.I am sharing images,interesting enough it does not work for Evernote application.I can share with Evernote by the default way.But it does not work with this code.I have experienced this only for the Evernote application.

This is my code :

```
public void doShareCustomDialog() {
    Bitmap curBitmap = ((ImagePagerAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter())
            .getCurrentBitmap();
    final Intent imageIntent = new Intent();
    imageIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    imageIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    imageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
            getImageUri(getActivity(), curBitmap));

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.setTitle("Choose application:");
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(R.color.black_overlay));
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    ListView lv = new ListView(getActivity());
    dialog.setContentView(lv);
    dialog.show();

    PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> launchables = pm
            .queryIntentActivities(imageIntent, 0);
    Collections
            .sort(launchables, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));

    final AppAdapter adapter = new AppAdapter(pm, launchables);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            ResolveInfo launchable = adapter.getItem(position);
            ActivityInfo activity = launchable.activityInfo;
            ComponentName name = new ComponentName(
                    activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
            imageIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            imageIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
            imageIntent.setComponent(name);
            startActivity(imageIntent);
        }
    });

}
```

This is the getUri() method:

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(),
            inImage, "Title", null);
    latestSharedImageURI = Uri.parse(path);
    return latestSharedImageURI;
}
```

This code here works perfectly fine,but its without the custom dialog,but with the default one.

```
public void doShare() {
    Bitmap curBitmap = ((ImagePagerAdapter) viewPager.getAdapter())
            .getCurrentBitmap();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/jpeg");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
            getImageUri(getActivity(), curBitmap));
    setShareIntent(intent);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,
            getResources().getText(R.string.share_choose)));
}
```

Comment: That's not the problem of your app. It's the problem of the `Evernote` app.

Comment: Please explain what "does not work" means.

Comment: When i click the Evernote button in the share menu list,nothing happens.And yes most likely its Evernote problem,but why this happens and what can i do to make it work.Is it some problem in the intent?

Comment: https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/android_intents.php

Comment: Well yes i looked into that and that part of the intent is ok.I think the problem is somewhere at the onItemClick method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to mention first that I'm an Evernote employee. I tried your snippet and it can work. It depends on this method:

```
imageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
        getImageUri(getActivity(), curBitmap));
```

You may want to post how you generate the Uri. In my test this definitely doesn't work if your file is in your app's internal storage. If the file is stored on the external storage, then your code works if the Uri is correct.

If you want to share a file from the internal storage you need to implement the [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) and generate the Uri with [getUriForFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#getUriForFile(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)). Then it worked with my test.

Comment: The difference to the working intent is **imageIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);**

Are you really sure that you want to reset and create a new task? This could end up unexpected results, if the user hits the back button. You do not return to your app, but stay in the other app which received the share intent. Also a new Activity isn't started, if the new app already has a back stack, e.g. open the Messaging app, open settings, press home, go to your app, share you Bitmap with the Messaging app. No new Message is being created.

Comment: Removing that line,fixed it,i still,dont really get,why this happened.But thanks a lot!